# How to define finite set of N elements in Coq?

Tags: set, coq

How to define, for general parameter N:nat , finite set of N elements, $ A_{0},...A_{N-1} $ ?
Is there an elegant way to do it by recursive definition? Could someone point me into good example of reasoning about such structures?

Comment: See standard library's [`Fin.t`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.Fin.html#t) for a recursive definition.

Comment: Yes, I do. I am looking for something much simpler, without such large number of dependency

Comment: What 'large number of dependency'? Sorry, I'm not following. It's in the standard library. You can copy the definition if you don't want to import the module. Sure, it's not an easy type to use, unlike ejgallego's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very convenient solution is to define the `n`th ordinal, `'I_n` as a record:

```
Record ordinal n := {
    val :> nat;
    _   : val < n;
}.
```

that is to say, a pair of a natural number, plus a proof that such natural number is less than `n`, where `< : nat -> nat -> bool`. It is very convenient to use a computable comparison operator here, in particular means that the proof itself is not very "important", which is what you normally want.

This is the solution used in [math-comp](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.fintype.html), and it has nice properties, mainly injectivity of `val`, `val_inj : injective val`, which means that you can reuse most of the standard operations over `nat` with your new datatype. Note that you may want to define addition as either `add i j := max n.-1 (i+j)` or as `(i+j) %% n`.

Additionally, the library linked above provides general definitions for working with finite types, including a bijection of them to their cardinal ordinal.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Record ordinal n`?

Comment: How do you instantiate a member of this type?

Comment: @apen `'I_n` has several constructors, usually you can use `@inord 9 3` to get an element of `'I_10` .