# Coq: Abbreviating definitions of inductive types

Tags: types, syntax, definition, coq, abbreviation

Suppose I have an inductive type w/ constructors of the same type, e.g.

```
Inductive A := a (x:nat)(y:Set) | b (x:nat)(y:Set).
```

Is it possible to abbreviate its definition, so that I wouldn't have to repeat the (possibly parametrized) type for each constructor, e.g. something like

```
Inductive A := (a | b) (x:nat)(y:Set).
```

Comment: YMMV, but in this case what I would do is to have a single constructor with a boolean flag on it.

Comment: @ejgallego: Good... and a `nat` flag if there're many constructors?

Comment: Likely an ordinal flag `'I_k`

Comment: Keep in mind that you can hack the display using notations, so the `true` and `false` case can be displayed (and parsed!) as a different inductive.

Comment: @ejgallego: Where (or how) are your ordinals defined? (My idea was to use `nat` in a partial function.)

Comment: There are may ways to define ordinals, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871971/how-to-define-finite-set-of-n-elements-in-coq but there are more examples floating around in SO.

Comment: @ejgallego: The only problem w/ displaying flag values as different notations is that it would be more coding than w/ different constructors